# How to import HTTPClient in Dr. Java?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am attempting to write a code to scrape websites and use httpclient. I am trying to import the proper classes to run my program, but it is saying the package does not exist. I have looked at their [API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/) to try to figure it out and still cannot. My code is:

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import java.util.Scanner  

public class Scraper3 { 

  public static String scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you download the JARs and put them on the classpath? This would probably be also a great time to make yourself familiar with Maven... It made _my_ life a lot easier...

Comment: I will look into Maven. I have not added the JARs to the classpath. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: [This article](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis1xx/resources/java/jar/jarindrjava.html) describes it for DRJava

Comment: Awesome. What would be the advantage of using Maven for this project?

Answer (score 0):

try: `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`